# Hammerspoon: filter application in use

Tags: macos, filter, lua, hammerspoon

I bind some key to execute script. I need to activite bind only when Visual Studio Code window is focused.

I see Hammerspoon filters functions but I don't understand how use it.

Application name: `Code`

```
hs.hotkey.bind({"ctrl"}, "b", function()
    local codeWindowFilter = hs.window.filter:setAppFilter('Code')
    codeWindowFilter:isAppAllowed("Code", function()

        mycode here

    end)
end)
```

but I get the error `attempt to call a nil value (method 'setAppFilter')`

Is this the correct way?
Is there way to put all bind into approved filter?

Thnak you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final solution is that one:

```
local frontmostApplication = hs.application.frontmostApplication()

if frontmostApplication and frontmostApplication:name() == "Code" then

   {my code here}

end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter app like this

```lua
    wf_terminal = hs.window.filter.new{'Terminal','iTerm2'}
    for _, win in ipairs(wf_terminal:getWindows()) do
        if win ~= nil and string.find(win:title(), "nvim") then
            moveWindowToLeftHalf(win)
            win:focus()
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs here (http://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.window.filter.html):

You need to follow this structure:

```
local wf=hs.window.filter
wf.default:setAppFilter('My IDE',{allowTitles=1})
```

OR

Create a new window filter as is described here:

> While you can customize the default windowfilter, it's usually advisable to make your customizations on a local copy via mywf=hs.window.filter.new(); the default windowfilter can potentially be used in several Hammerspoon modules and changing it might have unintended consequences...

Therefore, change your code to be this:

```
local codeWindowFilter = hs.window.filter.new():setAppFilter('Code')
```

The .new() method creates a new window filter. The :setAppFilter calls a method on the new object, and then returns the modified window filter object.

Comment: Thank you for you help, but I have problem with the next step. How to use the filter? If I use `local codeWindowFilter = hs.window.filter.new():setAppFilter('Code')
    codeWindowFilter:isAppAllowed(hs.application:title(), function()

        mycode here

    end)` "mycode" is not executed and it get error.

   
My goal is enable the shortcut or it's contained code only if a window of "Code" application is focused